# Printing parts of a dictionary by using a for loop Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, format

How could I print out the `Accountname, APIkey, APIsecret` for the `clients` dict? I want to print it in the format of the expected output.

Code:

```py
clients = {1: {'AccountName': 'Acount1', 'APIKey': 'sdhsdhjsd','APIsecret':'sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg'},
           2: {'AccountName':'Acount2', 'APIKey':'sdasdasdadc','APIsecret':'sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf'}}

for clients_info in clients.items():
    print("Accountname: ", clients_info['AccountName'], "APIkey: ", clients_info['APIKey'], "APIsecret: ", clients_info['APIsecret'])
```

Expected output:

```
Accountname: Acount1 APIkey: sdhsdhjsd APIsecret: sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg
Accountname: Acount2 APIkey: sdasdasdadc APIsecret: sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf
```

Actual output:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `clients.values()` instead of `clients.items()` if you aren't interested in the keys of the outer dictionary:

```py
for clients_info in clients.values():
     print("Accountname:", clients_info['AccountName'], "APIkey:", clients_info['APIKey'], "APIsecret:", clients_info['APIsecret'])
```

produces

```
Accountname: Acount1 APIkey: sdhsdhjsd APIsecret: sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg
Accountname: Acount2 APIkey: sdasdasdadc APIsecret: sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf
```

Also, `print()` automatically adds spaces between its arguments so you don't have to add an additional space after your output labels.

Answer (score 0):

When using `clients.items()` and a single iterable, each iterable is a tuple of the key to the value, i.e., `(key, value)`. You can unpack them by doing `for key, value in clients.items()` if you like, otherwise you must store them yourself after the for loop:

```py
for client_info_tuple in clients.items():
    client_info = client_info_tuple[1]
```

But I think the first option is neater. Since you don't need the index (from what I understand) you can either just do `clients.values()` or put a `_` in front of the index variable so your IDE doesn't complain about it.

If you're using Python >= 3.6, you can also use f-strings which make this sort of thing much nicer to look at, in my opinion:

```py
for _index, client_info in clients.items():
    print(
        f"Accountname: {client_info['AccountName']} "
        f"APIKey: {client_info['APIKey']} "
        f"APIsecret: {client_info['APIsecret']}"
    )
```

Output:

```
Accountname: Acount1 APIKey: sdhsdhjsd APIsecret: sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg
Accountname: Acount2 APIKey: sdasdasdadc APIsecret: sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf
```